# how making many submit button in one page laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8

I have several buttons to insert data into the database, but only one command works, while the others don't work, what should I do, I will give an example of the data I created

this is my controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // 
        $days = $request->hari;
        $hours = $request->jam;
        $minutes = $request->menit;
        $model = new Q_Topic_User;
        $model->status = $request->status;
        $model->topic_id = $request->topic_id;
        $model->timer = Carbon::now()->addDays($days)->addHours($hours)->addMinute($minutes);
        $topik = $request->topic_id;
        $model->user_create = auth()->id();
        // dd($request->all());
        $model->save();
               
        return redirect('qanswers/'. $topik);
    }

    public function storeAns(Request $request)
    {
        $modellama = Q_Answer::where('user_create', '=', $request->kode_user)
        ->Where('topic_id', '=', $request->topic_id)
        ->Where('question_id', '=', $request->question_id);

        $a = $request->user_answer;
        $b = $request->answer;

        if ($a === $b){
            $nilai = "1";
        }
        else{
            $nilai = "0";
        }

        if ($modellama >= "1"){
            $modellama->delete();
        }

        // dd($request->all());
        $model = new Q_Answer;
        $model->topic_id = $request->topic_id;
        $model->question_id = $request->question_id;
        $model->user_answer = $request->user_answer;
        $model->answer = $request->answer;
        $model->hasil = $nilai;
        $model->user_create = auth()->id();
        $topik = $request->topic_id;
            
        $model->save();
                
        return redirect('qanswers/'. $topik);
    }
public function storeTot(Request $request)
    {
        $tot_nilai = Q_Answer::select(DB::raw("CAST(SUM(hasil) as int) as tot_nilai"))
        ->Where('topic_id', '=', $request->topic_idi)
        ->Where('user_create', '=', auth()->id())
        ->pluck('tot_nilai');

        // dd($tot_nilai);

        $tot_soal = Q_Question::select(DB::raw("CAST(COUNT(topic_id) as int) as tot_soal"))
        ->Where('topic_id', '=', $request->topic_idi)
        ->pluck('tot_soal');

        dd($request->all());
        $model = new Q_Answer_Tot;
        $model->topic_id = $request->topic_idi;
        $model->totalsoal = $tot_soal;
        $model->totalnilai = $tot_nilai;
        $model->user_create = auth()->id();
        
        // dd($request->all());
        $model->save();
        $topik = $request->topic_id;
                
        return redirect('qanswers/'. $topik);
    }
```

blade :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('qanswers') }}"
                                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
                                        @foreach ($datas as $d_value)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success">Kirim data</button>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </form>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('qanswers.storeAns') }}"
                                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
                                        @foreach ($questionss as $q_value)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success">Kirim Pilihan Pertanyaan</button>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </form>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('qanswers.storeTot') }}"
                                        enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        @csrf
                                        @foreach ($questionss as $t_value)
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success">Kirim Pilihan Peserta</button>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </form>
```

my web.php :

```
Route::resource('/qanswers', Q_AnswersController::class);
Route::post('/storeAns',[Q_AnswersController::class, 'storeAns'])->name('storeAns');
Route::post('/storeTot',[Q_AnswersController::class, 'storeTot'])->name('storeTot');
```

i can save data in store but i can save data using storeAns and storeTot. I dont find error in laravel log but i can see my data using dd($request->all()); can u help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good practice to give each form an unique **id**.  With multiple forms and buttons, I would specify the **form** for the button. And you need to use **value** to figure out which button was pressed, especially when you are going to the same url in more than one form.

```html
<form method="POST" id="answers" action="{{ url('qanswers') }}"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @foreach ($datas as $d_value)
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success" value="form1">Kirim data</button>
   @endforeach
</form>

<form method="POST" id="storeans1" action="{{ url('qanswers.storeAns') }}"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @foreach ($questionss as $q_value)
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success" value="form2">Kirim Pilihan Pertanyaan</button>
   @endforeach
</form>

<form method="POST" id="storeans2" action="{{ url('qanswers.storeAns') }}"
   enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   @foreach ($questionss as $q_value)
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm bg-success" value="form3">Kirim Pilihan Pertanyaan</button>
   @endforeach
</form>
```

I have shown the value with **formx**. SInce you are creating many buttons for each form, each should have an unique value such as

```
form1btn1
form1btn2
form1btn3
```